# It is a bad practice to use Sun's proprietary Java classes?

Tags: java, sun

The compiler display warnings if you use Sun's proprietary Java classes. I'm of the opinion that it's generally a bad idea to use these classes. I read this somewhere. However, aside from the warnings are there any fundamental reasons why you should not use them?

Comment: Any functionality that is sufficiently general will be embodied in the official Java API. Is there really is something in the Sun classes that you need and cannot be done through the standard Java API? Can you give an example?

Comment: (I sometimes catched myself using the internal xerces for xml processing)

Comment: Well xerces is the default XML implementation when processing XML using JAXP. There is no need to reach down and use xerces directly.

Comment: The reason I posted is because I came across some code using sun.misc.BASE64Decoder. I changed it to use codec from apache. I knew this was the right thing to do but couldn't remember why.

Comment: I want to rant about those classes all day long for causing 80% of all problems in IKVM.NET.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Because they are internal APIs: they are subject to change in a **undocumented** or **unsupported** way and they are bound to a specific JRE/JDK (**Sun** in your case), limiting portability of your programs.

Try to avoid uses of such APIs, always prefer a public documented and specified class.

Comment: Some APIs under `com.sun.*` are experimental (the original APT API was for example). IIRC, Alex Buckley has a blog on the various statuses of these APIs. But yes, in general they may change or disappear in update releases and between vendors.

Comment: I've set my java editor (IntelliJ Idea) to exclude com.sun from intellisense suggestions.Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Is “APT” referring to [Academic Progress Tracker](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56917_01/cs9pbr4/eng/cs/lssr/concept_UnderstandingtheAcademicProgressTracker-fd7ffe.html)?

Comment: @FranklinYu Advanced Passenger Train. No, apt was Annotation Processing Tool. It briefly had it's own executable, `apt`, now part of `javac` (`-processor`, etc.)

Answer (score 24):

The [JDK 6 Documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/index.html) includes a link titled [Note About `sun.*` Packages](http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/faq/faq-sun-packages.html).  This is a document from the Java 1.2 docs, so references to `sun.*` should be treated as if they said `com.sun.*`

The most important points from it are:

> The classes that Sun includes with the
>   Java 2 SDK, Standard Edition, fall
>   into package groups `java.*`, `javax.*`,
>   `org.*` and `sun.*`. All but the `sun.*`
>   packages are a standard part of the
>   Java platform and will be supported
>   into the future. In general, packages
>   such as `sun.*`, that are outside of the
>   Java platform, can be different across
>   OS platforms (Solaris, Windows, Linux,
>   Macintosh, etc.) and can change at any
>   time without notice with SDK versions
>   (1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.3, etc). Programs
>   that contain direct calls to the `sun.*`
>   packages are not 100% Pure Java.

and

> Each company that implements the Java
>   platform will do so in their own
>   private way. The classes in `sun.*` are
>   present in the SDK to support the Sun
>   implementation of the Java platform:
>   the `sun.*` classes are what make the
>   Java platform classes work "under the
>   covers" for the Sun Java 2 SDK. These
>   classes will not in general be present
>   on another vendor's Java platform. If
>   your Java program asks for a class
>   "sun.package.Foo" by name, it may fail
>   with ClassNotFoundError, and you will
>   have lost a major advantage of
>   developing in Java.

Comment: As a "several years later" comment: There's no guarantee that `com.sun.*` won't change to `com.oracle.*` since Sun no longer exists.

Comment: That's not correct. Many `com.sun.*` packages are part of the documentated specification. It would be impossible to write JNDI LDAP or COSNaming code without them. The issue is the `sun.*` packages, which are an altogether different matter and specifically documented as such.

Comment: btw, trying to use the `sun.*` and `com.sun.*` classes will fail spectacularly on Java 9.

Comment: Not the `com.sun.*` classes. They are documented parts of the Sun/Oracle JDK.

Comment: I understand that `sun.*` is internal, but is there any source about `com.sun.*` being internal? And is there any example of `com.sun.*` package breaking in any version?

Comment: Related: [*What is inside com.sun package?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565708/what-is-inside-com-sun-package)

Answer (score 10):

Try running your code with a non-Sun JVM and see what happens...

(Your code will fail with a ClassNotFound exception)

Comment: This is a valid suggestion to identify the problem (*although not a proper answer*).

Comment: +1 for a very practical illustration of what most would consider a hypothetical future problem

Answer (score 7):

Yes, because nobody guarantees that these classes or API will be the same with the next Java release and I bet it's not guaranteed that those classes are available in Java versions from other vendors.

So you couple your code to special Java version and loose at least portability.

Answer (score 4):

Sun's proprietary Java classes are part of their Java implementation not part of the Java API their use is undocumented and unsupported. Since they are internal they can be changed at any time for any reason that the team working the Sun JVM decides.

Also Sun's Java implementation is not the only one out there! Your code would not be able portable to JVMs from other vendors like Oracle/BEA and IBM.

Answer (score 2):

Here is Oracle's answer: [Why Developers Should Not Write Programs That Call 'sun' Packages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a case that showed a real-world problem you can hit when you use these classes: we had code that would not compile because a method it was using on a sun.* class simply did not exist in OpenJDK on Ubuntu. So I guess when using these classes you can no longer say things like 'this works with Java 5', because it will only work on a certain Java implementation.

Comment: I can strongly recommend running your unittests on a different platform and JVM than you use for development.  A lot of interesting things tend to show up.