# Java JMC "MediaProvider" - mystery class

Tags: java, javadoc

[in a library i'm having problems with](http://github.com/angusforbes/jmcvideo/blob/master/src/jmcvideo/JMC.java) there is this class

```
com.sun.media.jmc.MediaProvider
```

which i want to have a look at.
i can't find a javadoc or anything for it, how do i find out its methods etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classes of the package `com.sun.*` (and `sun.*`) are **internal** classes which backs the standard Java API. They are undocumented and subject to changes among versions and builds. You should in fact [**never**](http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/faq/faq-sun-packages.html) make use of them in your Java code, else your code will break when you change the API implementation. Also see [this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834826/it-is-a-bad-practice-to-use-suns-proprietary-java-classes).

In this case, the `com.sun.media.jmc.MediaProvider` is part of the Sun reference implementation of the [JMF API](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/) ([javadocs here](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/)). You are supposed to make use of the classes documented in the JMF API only. The (abstract) factories/builders will invisibly provide the Sun reference implemtations.

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler), which supports more codecs than JMF, is free and open-source, and is actively developed and supported (unlike JMF).