# How to play mp3 files in java

Tags: java, mp3, jmf, jplayer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Playing .mp3 and .wav in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045384/playing-mp3-and-wav-in-java)

Friends,

please tell me link if this question already exist:

I want to play sounds of alphabet letters encoded in mp3, with different variations while playing it.

For example:

For the word "Apple" it would use 4 files: "A.mp3", "p.mp3", "l.mp3", "e.mp3". Also, I want to add some kind of delay between sounds, for example between "A.mp3" and "p.mp3" it would pause for 100 msecs and between "p.mp3" and "l.mp3" - 50 msecs.

Please tell me if there exists any class and/or attribute to do that.

Also, I would like to know if it is possible to stop and resume it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you looked at these pages?

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/faq/mp3/mp3.html

http://www.morgenstille.at/blog/how-to-play-a-mp3-file-in-java-simple-and-beautiful/

Comment: just posting links is not a good answer. additionally your second link is not working anymore, which shows why it is bad pratice for answering

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. You are welcome to add better / further answers.