# could not get audio input stream from input URL

Tags: java, runtime-error, javasound

I am trying to run a sound file in Java using this code:

```
  public class Audio3
  {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
      { 
        URL soundFile =new URL( 
          "http://everyayah.com/data/Ghamadi_40kbps/audhubillah.mp3");
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
        AudioPlayer.player.start(ais);
      }
  }
```

I am getting this exception

```
javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: 
    could not get audio input stream from input URL
```

Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: This will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045384/playing-mp3-and-wav-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [JavaSound info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info).

> ### MP3 decoding support
>
> The Java Sound API does not support many formats of sampled sound internally. In a 1.6.0_24 Oracle JRE `getAudioFileTypes()` will generally return {`WAVE, AU, AIFF`}. An MP3 decoder at least, is close by. **The `mp3plugin.jar` of the Java Media Framework supports decoding MP3s.**

I can vouch for that information since I've successfully loaded MP3s using Java Sound and the MP3 SPI (& also wrote the info. page ;) ).  The JMF installer download is becoming hard to find, but you can get the [`mp3plugin.jar`](http://pscode.org/lib/mp3plugin.jar) direct from where I put it for use in JWS apps.

Comment: Issue resolved, but if i use Google App Engine , i get this   javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment                     : Any Idea

Comment: *"Google App Engine"* The GAE is an almost entirely separate matter.  I have no experience with it.  If you want to pursue that, you'd be best asking a new question and adding the GAE tag to grab the attention of the people that know it.