# Playing a mp3 file in a client program

Tags: java, ftp, mp3, javasound

I'm trying to send a mp3 file from a server to a client and play it but I can't figure out how to do it. I've been looking at the Media and Media Player java classes but still don't understand how they work or know if it's the correct thing to use for this situation since I don't want the music stored on the computer after the program is closed. This is my first question so I'm sorry if there are any mistakes but I will learn.

Server code fragment:

```
if(number == songNumber)
{
  File song = files[i];

  byte[] bytearray  = new byte [(int)song.length()];
  FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(song);
  BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);

  bin.read(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);
  OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
  System.out.println("Sending Files...");

  os.write(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);
  os.flush();
  socket.close();
  bin.close();
  System.out.println("File transfer complete");
}
```

Client code fragment:

```
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("copy.doc");
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

byte [] bytearray  = new byte [filesize];
bytesRead = is.read(bytearray,0,bytearray.length);
currentTot = bytesRead;

do 
{
  bytesRead = is.read(bytearray, currentTot, (bytearray.length-currentTot));
  if(bytesRead >= 0) currentTot += bytesRead;
} 
while(bytesRead > -1);
{
  bos.write(bytearray, 0 , currentTot);
}
```

Comment: It needs an MP3 SPI.  See the [Java Sound info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 7 defines some nice classes so from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045384/playing-mp3-and-wav-in-java)

```
String bip = "bip.mp3";
Media hit = new Media(bip);
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
mediaPlayer.play();
```

If you need a Non-Java 7 method, do as Andrew says and use an MP3 SPI.

Comment: JLayer is overkill.  It (Java Sound) just needs an MP3 SPI to be able to play MP3.

Answer (score -1):

```
import sun.audio.*;
import java.io.*;

public class playsound{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
      FileInputStream fileau=new FileInputStream("D:/01.mid" );
      AudioStream as=new AudioStream(fileau);
      AudioPlayer.player.start(as);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {System.out.println("failed！");}
  }
}
```

hope this can help you.

Comment: They clearly want to play an MP3. THis method will only play WAV's and MIDI's as far as I am aware.

Comment: I remember there is some method in java to start local program on clint computer, can you use this?

Comment: that is, to start a local mp3 player to play mp3. If it is not allowed, maybe you need to import a package that plays mp3 music.

Comment: You could call a local program, but that is terrible. There is no guarantee that any one program is available and you can't account for every possible MP3 playing program.