# How to Play/Pause a mp3 file using the JavaZOOM JLayer library?

Tags: java

How would I add a Play/Pause button to the following code?

```
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;

try{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("mysong.mp3");
    Player playMP3 = new Player(fis);
    playMP3.play();
}
catch(Exception exc){
    exc.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Failed to play the file.");
}
```

Comment: This thread should help you, it covers everything pretty nicely : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045384/playing-mp3-and-wav-in-java

Comment: use MediaPlayer class

Comment: I seriously don't know why this question was closed. I know the answer and I was just typing it in. OP's not using the usual JMF and is asking a pretty straightforward question which has an answer that may not be obvious on the first sight. Sure, it's not the most well-behaved question of all time, but it makes sense to me.

Comment: @Slanec It's re-opened if you want to type said answer in.

Comment: @user2413200 Did the Integer.MAX_VALUE trick work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to use the [`AdvancedPlayer`](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/docs/docs1.0/javazoom/jl/player/advanced/AdvancedPlayer.html) class instead of just `Player`, because the simpler one can't really start playing the file in the middle.

You'll need to add a [`PlaybackListener`](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/docs/docs1.0/javazoom/jl/player/advanced/PlaybackListener.html) and listen for the `stop()` method. Then you can simply start again from the moment you left off.

```
private int pausedOnFrame = 0;

AdvancedPlayer player = new AdvancedPlayer(fis);
player.setPlayBackListener(new PlaybackListener() {
    @Override
    public void playbackFinished(PlaybackEvent event) {
        pausedOnFrame = event.getFrame();
    }
});
player.play();
// or player.play(pausedOnFrame, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

This will remember the frame playing was paused on (if paused).

And now, when Play is pressed again after a pause, you'll check whether `pausedOnFrame` is a number between 0 and the number of frames in the file and invoke [`play(int begin, int end)`](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/docs/docs1.0/javazoom/jl/player/advanced/AdvancedPlayer.html#play%28int,%20int%29).

Note that you should know the number of frames in the file before you do this. If you don't, you could try to play all the frames via this trick:

```
player.play(pausedOnFrame, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

That said, the API doesn't seem very helpful in your case, but it's the best you can do other than swiching to a different library.

Comment: The play() method of AdvancedPlayer is internally using Integer.MAX_VALUE too, so it should be fine. I took quick look at the implementation.

Comment: I've tried to implements this too, but at resuming i got a random point access to track..., i've checked the event.getFrame(), it seems the value passed is not corresponding to what we're listening...