# Sending audio dircetly to the speakers java

Tags: java, audio, byte, bufferedoutputstream

The title basically tells my story, I would like to send audio directly to the speaker system from a java program, i was thinking of trying to write directly to the speakers in /dev/ in linux using bytes obtained from an audio file, which i'm not sure would work, but in Windows i'm beyond stumped.  I was thinking along the lines of something like this:

```
public void play(byte[] audio){
   if(OS.isWindows){//This is where i have no idea, maybe write to javasound with jmf?
}
if(OS.isLinux){
    BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/dev/blahblah");
    bout.write(audio)
    bout.flush();
    bout.close();
 }
```

My code almost seems to simple to me, not that i want complicated code, but i want working code.  I havent actually tried the above code, in fear that i dont know what im doing, and could possibly hurt or interrupt something in my pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just `cat tune.wav > /dev/dsp` anymore (not without [some tricks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28045)), and the way your attempting this *sounds* too low level - so choose a library.

You might have luck with the standard ones such as [javax.sound](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/) (simple) and [JMF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html) (more features).

Or you could try a third party library such as [Jogamp JOAL](http://jogamp.org/joal/) (feature rich), which you can use it with Windows and Linux (through native libraries).

**EDIT: For MP3**

1. Just noticed with Java 7's [javafx](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx) you can do easily, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10237397/573057)
2. To roll your own with javax.sound: follow this tutorial on creating for [SPI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html)* to create an [AudioFileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/spi/AudioFileReader.html) handling MP3s. (*Note the previous SPI link is javax.sound specific, but [SPI is a general concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface)*)
3. Alternatively JMF can handle mp3s [with this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-137625.html), and you can lookup how to nest jars etc if you're determined to provide a single artifact.

Comment: My only problem with javax.sound, is there isnt support for mp3.  I know through some complicated procedure that you can decode the mp3, but I dont know how to do that.  If you could give me a sample piece of code for javax.sound, just on how to decode the mp3, i'd love to use the sound lib included

Comment: Ah thank you, this should work well! Just one question, with javafx, do i need to nest the jars with mine during compilation, for an easy transfer from user to user?

Comment: Sorry, just read that JavaFX Comes included with Java7, ignore my previous comment. -_-