# How to remove LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY in Javasound? [code inside]

Tags: java, mp3, javasound

I have saw this code somewhere in this area. I want to play the .wav file once but not continuously. How can I do that? I try removing the LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY line but it does not work.

```
URL url = new URL("http://pscode.org/media/leftright.wav");
                            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                            // getAudioInputStream() also accepts a File or InputStream
                            AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.
                                getAudioInputStream( url );
                            clip.open(ais);
                            clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
                            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Close to exit!");
                                }
                            });
```

And if possible. Can I play mp3 files as well. Because when I try to replace it as mp3, my code crashes. Also, I want to get the file from my computer. Not on the internet. Can anyone help me?

Comment: *"I have saw this code somewhere in this area."*  Umm.. I'm guessing you saw it on the page I linked in your earlier question - which now seems to be deleted..  In any case, it comes from the [Java Sound info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) which also mentions MP3 explicitly and how to provide support for it.  *"I try removing the LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY line but it does not work."*  Did you actually try glancing at the documentation on that method?  Another answer besides `start()` should have been intuitively obvious! ..

Comment: .. *"Also, I want to get the file from my computer. Not on the internet."*  Oh for pity's sake!  1) What does that code comment in the snippet you quoted mean to you?  2) It is possible to form an URL that points to a) A place on the internet b) A file on the local file system c) A resource embedded in a Jar file (stored either locally or on the internet).

Comment: I have resolved it already. Thank you! I should have read first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `clip.start()` instead of `clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY)`
- Use `File` or `getResourceAsStream()` instead of `URL` and feed it to `getAudioInputStream` the same way
- See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045384/playing-mp3-and-wav-in-java) for mp3 files

Comment: Thanks! Do i need to download the one with JAVA FX from oracle?

Comment: If you're going to use `javafx.scene.media` for mp3 playing, yes. There are other answers in link I gave, providing alternatives as well.

Comment: `getResourceAsStream()` is typically an unbuffered stream, whereas the `AudioSystem` requires a buffered stream.

Comment: I have one question with you huys. I have 2 .wav files on my code, i want to pause the current the song and replace by the other. What happening right now is they play simultaneously. What can I do with that?

Comment: *"I have one question.."*  'Famous last words'.  You've already asked and had answered a question, so you should (search first and) start a new question.  Also note that if you **do** ask a new question, I'll be looking back through my [answers on Java sound](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A418556+[javasound]) for a duplicate of it, as I'm sure I've answered it before.  Please save me the trouble by looking through those answers.