# Copying a resource outside the current jar

Tags: java, resources, unzip

I have a game which plays a background music.

I'm using an mp3 library that doesn't support in-jar reading, so I can't use the `getClass().getResource()` method to find the resource and pass the url to the library, I have to extract that file and pass its path to the library.

I'm using this method to copy the file outside the jar:

```
File f = new File("15.mp3"); //the music file for output

InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("15.mp3"); //the mp3 inside the jar
BufferedOutputStream buf = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
byte[] read = new byte[1024];
while (is.read(read) > -1) {
    buf.write(read);
    buf.flush();
}
buf.close();
```

This method works, the sound gets played, but it's a bit scratchy (the original -which is stored in the jar- is perfect).

Am I doing something wrong with the copy? Am I supposed to do something else to correctly copy an in-jar resource outside the jar package?

Comment: Why not use Java's media player? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045384/playing-mp3-and-wav-in-java

Comment: @MirroredFate Because with `AudioInputStream` it didn't work, it said "can't open file with this format". And I can't use javafx

Comment: @JonSkeet I know you can help me! :P