# Change Mixer to output sound to in java

Tags: java, audio, mp3, wav, mixer

I am trying to play a wav/mp3 to my virtual audio cable, I have been searching for hours but can't seem to find how to achieve this. I have been able to play sound in both formats but I can't get it to output to 'Line-1' rather than 'Speakers'

Any helpful links or example code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get an array of all [`Mixer`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Mixer.html) on the current platform, you may use [`AudioSystem#getMixerInfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getMixerInfo--):

```
static void printAllMixerNames() {
    for(Mixer.Info info : AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()) {
        System.out.println(info.getName());
    }
}
```

If your virtual cable is available, it will be in the array. For example, on my Mac the following is printed:

```
Java Sound Audio Engine
Built-in Input
Soundflower (2ch)
Soundflower (64ch)
Pro Tools Aggregate I/O
```

(Soundflower is a virtual device.)

To get some specific `Mixer` you unfortunately need to do String evaluation. So you need to discover its name, vendor, whatever, beforehand or give the user an option to pick one from a list.

```
static Mixer getMixerByName(String toFind) {
    for(Mixer.Info info : AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()) {
        if(toFind.equals(info.getName())) {
            return AudioSystem.getMixer(info);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Once you have a particular `Mixer` you can obtain a `Line` or `AudioInputStream` from it. You can obtain a `Clip` from it through [`AudioSystem#getClip(Mixer.Info)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getClip-javax.sound.sampled.Mixer.Info-).

> I am trying to play a wav/**mp3**...

`javax.sound.sampled` does not support `mp3`. [Alternatives can be found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045384/playing-mp3-and-wav-in-java)