# Is it possible to code on Java program like Soundflower?

Tags: java, audio

The idea of [Soundflower](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower) it is to allow applications to pass audio to other applications by routing your audio output as an audio input to the system. I do not know much about Java in this area and I just would like to know if it's possible to write using it..

Comment: No, Java can't do this. SoundFlower ihas to run as a system extension to do this, you can't do that with Java.

Answer (score 0):

To create an Audio mixer, you can use the Audio system class. You can find the official documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getMixerInfo--) to know more about implementation.

Quick Tip :

```
AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(MyClazz.class.getResource("music.wav"));
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(audioIn);
clip.start();
```

Also go through the following threads which must give you more insights on this .

[How to run .mp3 in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045384/playing-mp3-and-wav-in-java)

[Change mixer to output sound using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026042/change-mixer-to-output-sound-to-in-java)

Comment: The code example is a bit suspicious. I'd trust it more if the Java output was done via a SourceDataLine. A Clip will not allow output until the entire sound file is opened and loaded into RAM. In other words, the sound file has to be finite. SourceDataLine, however, can continuously read and write with open lines.