# Java: Play .wav file when panel is opened

Tags: java, audio, canvas, jframe, clip

I need a .wav file to loop while a Canvas contained in a JFrame is opened, and stop when closed. I tried looking around but nothing seems to work, is there any way to do this with Clip? Can anyone giving me a simple example?
Thank you very much.

EDIT:
I know how to loop a Clip file or play it once, it just doesn't stop when the frame is closed, it keeps looping.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Playing .mp3 and .wav in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045384/playing-mp3-and-wav-in-java)

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077521/learn-java/java-tip-24--how-to-play-audio-in-applications.html or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045384/playing-mp3-and-wav-in-java