# JavaFX audio doesn't seem to be playing

Tags: java, audio, javafx, media-player, media

I am fairly new to JavaFX and recently wanted to play audio with an MP3 file rather than WAV. From what I can tell, I am doing things correctly and I don't get any errors, but I also don't hear any sound.

I will post the parts of my code that matter below. If I'm missing something please let me know. Thanks.

```
try {
    URL sound = getClass().getResource("/resources/origin.mp3");
    Media hit = new Media(sound.toExternalForm());
    musicPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
    musicPlayer.setVolume(1.0);
}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("whoops: " + e);
}
checkMusic();
```

Check Music Method:

```
public void checkMusic() {
    if(music)
        musicPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
    else
        musicPlayer.stop();
}
```

I also tried just `musicPlayer.play();` as well.

**EDIT**

And yes, I am sure the code within the `if` statement runs, I have checked it with `println`, and they print out. The `music` boolean is just a controller for settings in the program/game.

Comment: If execution in `checkMusic` hits `musicPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);` it should be fine. Are you sure that you don't have any "whoops: .." in your console? Just because if you use leading slash ("/") when using getResource it will use the project root as base. How the calling class and the MP3 resource are placed in the directory structure?

Comment: It most definitely executes, because I've checked with `println`s. And the directory should be fine to, because it worked when I was using a .wav file. It is located in the bin folder, then in a folder called resources along with other things. And as far as I can tell there's no "whoops" in the console because I handled most of the problems already. (And trust me there were a few because of how new I am to JavaFX lol)

Comment: @DVarga oh and also, I may have found something. When I do `System.out.println(hit.getDuration();` it says unknown, and `getTracks()` is also unknown. Could this mean anything?

Answer (score -1):

instead of

```
Media hit = new Media(sound.toExternalForm());
```

try this:

```
final Media media = new Media(sound.toString());
```

Comment: Tried it and no change.