# I want my Java program to play a song?

Tags: java

I want my Java program to play a song while the program is running, What would be the sample code to have my java program play a tune with file name lets say, :
'hillsong.mp3' ? also if it is not too much to ask is my program well written? Or should I add separate some methods into seperate classes?

```
import java.awt.*;
import sun.audio.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AudioandImage extends JFrame {
    public ImageIcon image1;
    public JLabel label1;
    public ImageIcon image2;
    public JLabel label2;
    public JLabel text;

    AudioandImage() {
        setLayout (new BorderLayout());
        image1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("losangeles.jpg"));

        label1 = new JLabel(image1);
        add(label1,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        image2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("elsalvador.jpg"));

        label2 = new JLabel(image2);
        add(label2,BorderLayout.CENTER);

         text = new JLabel("<html><ul>My name is : Erik  Landaverde "
                    + "<li/>Some facts about myself: </li> "
                    + "<li/>I was born and raised in South Central Los Angeles</li>"
                    + "<li/>Have a Salvadorean background</li>"
                    + "<li/>My favorite sport is soccer</li>"
                    + "<li/>Lastly... I am a programmer!</li></ul></html>", SwingConstants.CENTER);

         add(text,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AudioandImage gui = new AudioandImage();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.pack();
        gui.setTitle("A Little About Myself");

        }

}
```

Comment: Please only use code snippets on *runnable code*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Playing .mp3 and .wav in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045384/playing-mp3-and-wav-in-java)