# how to create a stop button to my mediaPlayer

Tags: java, javafx, android-mediaplayer

so I have code created allowing me to add songs to my music player by browsing music files on your computer and then a button is created with the song name and file path so it can be played. Each time you browse and pick a song a new mediaplayer is a assigned to the newly created song button which plays the song when clicked. I want to add a stop button that will stop either the currently playing song or all songs.

here is how I create song buttons:

```
  public void makeSongButton(Song song) {
   MyButton myButton = new MyButton(song, "Play " + song.getName() + " (" + 
  song.getDuration() + ")", this.nextX, this.nextY);

//update nextY
this.nextY++;

// add to buttons list
this.buttons.add(myButton);


myButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
      //code to play a song modified from stackoverflow user jasonwaste's answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045384/playing-mp3-and-wav-in-java
      //system.out.println("play!!!");
      labelError.setText("play!");
      final MyButton myButton = (MyButton)event.getSource();
      final Song song = myButton.getSong();
      String songFile = song.getFile();
      Media media = new Media(new File(songFile).toURI().toString());
      MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
      mediaPlayer.play();


      //update player state...

      labelMsg.setText(song.getName());
    }
});
```

}

This function is called when someone clicks on the button BrowseButton that shows up everytime you pull up the program shown bellow:

```
  public void makeBrowseButton(Stage primaryStage, BMPData bmpData) {

 browseButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

    labelError.setText("browse!");

    // create fileChooser so user can browse
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();                                                                            // create object
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Audio Files", "*.wav", "*.mp3", "*.aac"));    //filter for music files
    if ( !parentPath.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {                                                                                //go to previous directory if exists
            File parentPathFile = new File(parentPath);
            fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(parentPathFile);
    }
    File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);                                                           // display the dialog box

    // processing IF file was chosen
    if (selectedFile != null) {
      // extract song name and file name from selected file object
      String name = selectedFile.getName();
      String wholePath = selectedFile.getPath();
          parentPath = selectedFile.getParent();

          Song song = new Song(name, wholePath);
      //update library
      bmpData.setNewSong(song);

      //make a button for the song
      makeSongButton(song);


      createDisplay(primaryStage, bmpData);
    }
  }
});
```

}

So in the last bit of browsebutton we call makeSongButton that creates a button for the song so it can be played, but each makeSongbutton call creates a new mediaplayer and I want to be able to create a stop button that stops all mediaPlayers....

Comment: Looks like your `MediaPlayer` needs to have a greater scope.

Comment: my MediaPlayer is actually 6 files I didn't want to add too much stuff though..

Comment: I don't understand your reply. Do you know what it mean to make a variable have a greater scope?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with this...

```
Button btn_stop = new Button("stop it!");
btn_stop.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            System.out.println("Stop Media Player");
        }
    });
```