# Google Text to Speech played with my speaker

Tags: java, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I would like a text as input to reproduce the content of that text as a synthesized voice with the speakers of my computer. The application I'm developing is in Java and to get the desired result I'm using the Google-test-to-speech libraries. I started with the following code: 
https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/libraries

but as you can see the voice message is saved on file and not reproduced with the speakers. So my question is how can I reproduce the voice message with the speakers of the computer running the application?

```
import com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.AudioEncoding;
import com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.SsmlVoiceGender;
import com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.SynthesisInput;
import com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.SynthesizeSpeechResponse;
import com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.TextToSpeechClient;
import com.google.cloud.texttospeech.v1.VoiceSelectionParams;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;


public class QuickstartSample {

  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    // Instantiates a client
    try (TextToSpeechClient textToSpeechClient = TextToSpeechClient.create()) {
      // Set the text input to be synthesized
      SynthesisInput input = SynthesisInput.newBuilder()
            .setText("Hello, World!")
            .build();

      // Build the voice request, select the language code ("en-US") and the ssml voice gender
      // ("neutral")
      VoiceSelectionParams voice = VoiceSelectionParams.newBuilder()
          .setLanguageCode("en-US")
          .setSsmlGender(SsmlVoiceGender.NEUTRAL)
          .build();

      // Select the type of audio file you want returned
      AudioConfig audioConfig = AudioConfig.newBuilder()
          .setAudioEncoding(AudioEncoding.MP3)
          .build();

      // Perform the text-to-speech request on the text input with the selected voice parameters and
      // audio file type
      SynthesizeSpeechResponse response = textToSpeechClient.synthesizeSpeech(input, voice,
          audioConfig);

      // Get the audio contents from the response
      ByteString audioContents = response.getAudioContent();

      // Write the response to the output file.
      try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("output.mp3")) {
        out.write(audioContents.toByteArray());
        System.out.println("Audio content written to file \"output.mp3\"");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Playing .mp3 and .wav in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045384/playing-mp3-and-wav-in-java)

Comment: The fact is that I don't want to write a file and then read it, It's a waste of resources. I would like to use the audio data "ByteString audioContents" directly to play the voice message

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the audio content to an InputStream and then use [javazoom Player](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/docs/docs1.0/javazoom/jl/player/Player.html) to play it

```
    import javazoom.jl.decoder.JavaLayerException;
    import javazoom.jl.player.Player;

    SynthesizeSpeechResponse response = textToSpeechClient.synthesizeSpeech(input, voice,audioConfig);
    InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getAudioContent().toByteArray());
    Player playMP3;
    playMP3 = new Player(targetStream);
    playMP3.play();
```

Comment: can you add some description to your code, code only answers are considered low quality