# How to play MP3 files that are in the resources folder in a Jar file?

Tags: java, jar, stream, mp3, executable-jar

I'm trying to access the MP3 files that are located inside the resources folder insidea jar file. I got some issues, they can't be readed.

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javazoom.jlgui.basicplayer.BasicPlayer;
import javazoom.jlgui.basicplayer.BasicPlayerException;

public class MP3 {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());


    private BasicPlayer player;


    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public MP3() {
        player = new BasicPlayer();
    }

    public void changeSong(song) {

        // Change song now
        String pathToMp3 = System.getProperty("user.dir") + this.getClass().getResource(song);
        try {
            player.open(new URL("file:///" + pathToMp3));
            player.play();
            logger.info("Playing the song: " + song);
        } catch (MalformedURLException | BasicPlayerException e) {
            logger.info("Could not turn on MP3 music from: " + pathToMp3);
        }

    }

}
```

The pathToMp3 looks like this:
[image]

I have solved a similar issue with CSV read. Instead of reading from resources. I read the resources as streams.

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/file.txt"); 
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

But the problem here is that

```
layer.open(new URL("file:///" + pathToMp3));
```

Takes the argument URL, not stream or string. Do you know how to stream MP3:s from the resources folder inside a executable JAR file?

**Update:**

```
       // Change song now
        String pathToMp3 = getClass().getResource(song).toString();
        InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(song);
        try {
            player.open(in);
            player.play();
            logger.info("Playing the song: " + song);
        } catch (BasicPlayerException e) {
            logger.info("Could not turn on MP3 music from: " + pathToMp3);
        }
```

Gives the error:

[image]

Comment: Since `this.getClass().getResource(song);` returns a `URL`, have you considered just trying `player.open(this.getClass().getResource(song))`?

Comment: Also, check the `song` value, for simplicity, make sure it's a absolute path from the top of you package structure to your resource, ie `/resources/HappyHappJoyJoy.mp3`

Comment: @MadProgrammer It gave the same error as before.

Comment: Perhaps use the ```Player``` class instead. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24337995/11226302 for the code

Comment: @ShivamPuri I found out that the current object have a file stream argument as well. But that didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I updated the question. Look for the **update**

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Look at the path.  Is `/se/danielmartensson/pijuckbox/Song0.mp3` the correct location for the file (within your Jar)?  I'd unzip the Jar a verify the location of the file (and ensure it's been included)

Comment: Also perhaps you should try printing the stack trace in the catch block. Maybe that gives a better idea of what is happening! ```e.printStackTrace();```

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's correct path. It's a se.danielmartensson.pijukebox package in Java. But I tried to read the exception now and I got  "javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException"

Comment: @ShivamPuri Yes. The stacktrace is "javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException"

Comment: Notice that this is on a Raspberry Pi. But Java runs everywhere ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the `BasicPlayerTest` example from [here](http://www.javazoom.net/jlgui/developerguide.html) and modified the play method to take an `URL`.

Then running the main works from the project and after the export in the jar.

Note that I copied the `resources` folder inside the src folder.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BasicPlayerTest test = new BasicPlayerTest();
    test.play(test.getClass().getResource("/resources/test.mp3")); 
}
```

The url I am seeing in the log is:
`jar:file:/C:/Temp/mp3.jar!/resources/test.mp3`

Comment: Hmm. Thanks! I tried that on my Ubuntu computer. It works! But not on Raspberry Pi.

Comment: You might get a better answer on the [raspberrypi stackexchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/). Does it actually work if you put the mp3 outside of the jar?