# Java using mp3, ogg and wav files with javax.sound.sampled.Clip (or getting the bitrate of the sound file)

Tags: java, audio, javasound, tritonus

My goal is to play multiple mp3, ogg, or wav music files at the same time in order to create adaptative music in a video game.

Instead of using the Clip class from the java sound API, I managed to create a class named Track which, thanks to mp3spi, and vorbisspi, can read mp3, ogg, and wav files by writing the audio data in a SourceDataLine.
I found this solution thanks to this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17737483/13326269

Everything works fine with a thread into the stream function so I can create many Track objects to play multiple sounds at the same time. But I want to create a function like `void setMicrosecondPosition(long microseconds);` from the Clip class.

I tried many things and I found a way to do it :

```
in = getAudioInputStream(new File(file).getAbsoluteFile());
int seconds = 410;
int bitrate = 320; //in kbit/s
in.skip(seconds*bitrate*1000/8); // divided by 8 because the skip method use bytes.
```

But I need the bitrate of the file. So, how can I get the **bitrate** of any sound file? Or better, how can I use mp3 and ogg files with the **javax.sound.sampled.Clip** class.

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you really do have working `AudioInputStreams`, the `skip` function references a number of bytes which should be a fixed amount per frame, determined by the audio format. For example stereo, 16-bit would be 4 bytes per frame, regardless. So you should be able to use the frame rate (e.g., 44100 frames/sec) to skip to the desired start point.

Another dodge would be to read but ignore the bytes incoming from the `AudioInputStream` in a method similar to the `stream` method in your link solution's example. You this can pretty quickly get you to the desired point, since you won't be blocked by the sdl `write()`. But if that works, the `skip` method should also work and would be preferable.