# What is inside com.sun package?

Tags: java

Like `javax` contains the extensions, what is the `com.sun` package supposed to contain?

Comment: Things like `com.sun.mail.smtp` and `com.sun.net.httpserver`, I suppose. http://www.google.ca/search?q=java+com.sun&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It contains <s>Sun</s> Oracle reference implementations of the standard Java (EE) APIs. Among others [Mojarra](https://github.com/javaee/mojarra) (the reference JSF implementation of Oracle) and [Glassfish](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish) (the reference Java EE implementation of Oracle) use this package. It's preferable to not use those classes directly in your code as it would make your code tight coupled to the implementation. Coding against the `java(x)` API directly enables you to change the implementation without changing your code (e.g. MyFaces instead of Mojarra and JBoss AS instead of Glassfish). Also JDK's own `HttpServer` sits in the `com.sun.*` package, see [Simple HTTP server in Java using only Java SE API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732109/simple-http-server-in-java-using-only-java-se-api/3732328#3732328).

Please note that the `com.sun.*` package should not be confused with `sun.*` package which are the internal classes behind Oracle JRE which you should [absolutely not](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/faq-sun-packages.html) import/use in your code as it would make your code tight coupled to the JRE make/version. Not using `sun.*` package at all enables you to run your code on all other JRE implementations (OpenJDK, GCJ, etc).

Comment: `java.` APIs that uses the `sun.` package - how are they staying supported when they depend on unsupported packages themselves?

Comment: @Lealo Because they're maintained by same people.

Comment: These people then make sure that whatever they are using from the sun.package  works? Otherwise they come up with - or use other packages to replace them - thus guranteeing their own `java.` package keeps working. Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: @Lealo They're unsupported for use by external developers. If there weren't supported at all for any use, there wouldn't be any point in their existence.

Comment: @BalusC [JEP 403](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/403) says the following, which seems to contradict your statement that it is okay to use the `com.sum.*` packages in general:  "*Most com.sun.\* packages in the JDK are for internal use*". The document makes a few explicit exceptions, however.

Comment: @Lii: *.. in the JDK ..*.

Answer (score 1):

There are many places which use `com.sun` packages (some of which are mentioned in other answers).   This answer just specifically addresses the use of `com.sun` within JavaFX.  [JavaFX is a UI library which is part of OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/openjfx/).

A lot of the [JavaFX implementation is in `com.sun` classes](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt/file/tip/modules/graphics/src/main/java/com/sun).  When JavaFX was open sourced, the [following comment](http://fxexperience.com/2012/02/a-short-tour-through-javafx-ui-common/) was made by the JavaFX developers regarding the use of `com.sun` classes within JavaFX:

> As always, non-public API (or rather, unsupported API, meaning anything that is not in the javafx namespace such as `com.sun.*`) cannot be depended on from release to release.  But for those of you wondering how things work, there is some very important stuff buried in the unsupported packages, and for those of you wanting to actually hack on OpenJFX, this will be of even greater interest.

Comment: However this only applies to JavaFX. All the JNDI and JavaMail providers are also supplied in `com.sun`, as are many other documented extensions, and they most certainly can be depended on from release to release.

Comment: Yes agreed, there are certain Java components, such as javamail, for which the end user can use `com.sun` classes.  But for those libraries, the relevant `com.sun` apis are part of the publicly published javadoc for the component.  For JavaFX, and many other Java system components, this is not the case and `com.sun` apis in those components are reserved for internal usage, are not documented In published javadoc and should not be used by an end user.

Answer (score -1):

Packages for internal use which you are not supposed to need access to directly.  They can be changed or dropped in any version of Java.  You can find the source for all sun.* and com.sun.* packages in the OpenJDK.

Comment: The `com.sun` namespace is not intended for the JDK implementation: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html

Comment: @raphw can you add a link which supports your statement.  Your link doesn't even mention com.sun.*

Comment: Well, the fact they do not even mention `com.sun.*` but write an extra section on the use of `sun.*` is a first hint. Also, Sun Microsystem released all their non-JCL Java code under `com.sun`: http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|com.sun where the use of `com.sun` classes is obviously intended to be legal. Also, some of the JDK tools like doclets are build arround the `com.sun` namespace.

Comment: "The com.sun namespace is not intended for the JDK implementation". What does that mean? com.sun is what JavaDoc dockets and taglets are specified in, as you mention in your second comment.

Comment: There is an explicit warning of Oracle (and formerly by Sun) not to use the `sun.*` packages because they contain the internal JVM implementation. No such warning exists for the `com.sun.*` namespace. The only thing, the two namespaces have in common is the word *sun*. This is reflected in the accepted answer to this question.

Comment: Much of `com.sun` consists of documented parts of the Sun/Oracle JDK or extensions, such as all the JNDI providers, all the JavaMail providers, the HTTP server, the Javadoc taglets, ... As such they most certainly cannot be arbitrarily changed or dropped from release to release of the JDK.