# NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/media/imageio/stream/RawImageInputStream

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, tomcat7, jai

guys am fed up of `NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/media/imageio/stream/RawImageInputStream` error at run time. Some times it is able to find this class and sometimes not!
I clean my tomcat directory, my target path again build my war file, change the server and deploy path , change the build order and export ! 
am using eclipse ide and this is highly irritating and there is a tremendous decline in development time due this exception every time at run time.

**Need a way such that every time tomcat needs to locate its class file, its  a success!**
Please help here! !

- i tried putting all jars related to jai in the `tomcat lib` folder
- adding as external jar to the project

still no success!

some alternative guys! its working completely fine on production ! 
but on local its giving run time errors! :( 
eclipse fault ? 
NEED SOLUTION! Thanks ! !

Comment: am trying all possible (even absurd things)! any solution to this error !

Comment: Are you using a Sun/Oracle JVM to run your application? That is an internal package you're not meant to reference it directly. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565708/what-is-inside-com-sun-package

Comment: am using servlets, it has its own jvm and am using these three packages jai_codec-1.1.3.jar,
jai_core-1.1.3.jar,
jai-imageio-1.2.jar

Comment: At the very least, post a stack trace. It would probably also help if you post the code involved. And perhaps edit your question to look less like a rant. :-) PS: Are you sure the 1.1.3 and 1.2 versions are compatible? Perhaps they contain duplicate/overlapping classes?

Comment: am not getting the exception since 4 5 days and yes there might be some compatibility issues.
anyway if i get any exception will post here. Thanks for reply sir.

Comment: Is there any news on this issue? I'm facing same problem and I wonder how you solved if it's not disappeared by itself.

Comment: The answer has been given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48295907/jai-imageio-noclassdeffounderror-for-rawimageinputstream