# JAI ImageIO NoClassDefFoundError for RawImageInputStream

Tags: javax.imageio, jai

I am very confused with this issue.  I am using 1.3.0 version on jai-imageio-core please check the dependecy below and I am at complete loss to figure out from the jar how can one class file (RawImageReaderSpi) is loaded in JVM but RawImageInputStream is not loaded.

I have deployed my spring boot web service in tomcat 7 container.

This issue pops up randomly and I have noticed that when I have restarted the TC container and deployed new version of my service, this issue shows up intermittently.

**Any lead is highly appreciated.**

I have spent a day trying to figure out what is wrong and ended up feeling stupid

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
    <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
    <artifactId>jai-imageio-jpeg2000</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/jaiimageio/stream/RawImageInputStream
        at com.github.jaiimageio.impl.plugins.raw.RawImageReaderSpi.canDecodeInput(RawImageReaderSpi.java:102) ~[jai-imageio-core-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO$CanDecodeInputFilter.filter(ImageIO.java:567) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.advance(ServiceRegistry.java:821) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.(ServiceRegistry.java:815) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.getServiceProviders(ServiceRegistry.java:516) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.getImageReaders(ImageIO.java:646) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1438) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1352) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at my-package.a.b(a.java:155) ~[classes/:na]
        at my-package.a.b(a.java:181) ~[classes/:na]
        at my-package.a.b(a.java:84) ~[classes/:na]
        at my-package.a$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5f66283f.invoke() ~[spring-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717) ~[spring-aop-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:267) ~[spring-tx-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653) ~[spring-aop-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at my-package.a$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dfc04a57.b() ~[spring-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at my-package.a.b(c.java:165) ~[classes/:na]
        at my-package.a$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$67dbe4b2.invoke() ~[spring-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717) ~[spring-aop-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:267) ~[spring-tx-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653) ~[spring-aop-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at my-package.a$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d153236a.processApprovedApplications() ~[spring-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65) ~[spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81) [spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
```

Comment: Do you deploy the jai-imageio-core JAR as part of your Web app (based on the symptoms, I guess you are)? Please read [this](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#deploying-the-plugins-in-a-web-app). The documentation link is from my TwelveMonkeys ImageIO project, but the same issue applies for JAI or any other ImageIO plugin as well.

Comment: Thanks for this. Well, this seems bit more promising in terms of explanation. I can certainly try this out. This issue really can't be reproduced by following any certain steps. So I won't know for sure if the suggested changes have worked. I had this issue about a year ago and yesterday. And most of the time, container restart works. Anyway, I will definitely give it a go.

Comment: @Herald I'm wondering how to define listener configuration in spring boot? Any idea?

Comment: Oh, I just read this -- https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/issues/16#issuecomment-326128071 someone has already explained.

Comment: I tried the approach of ImageIO.scanForPlugins(), sadly it didn't work.

Comment: Good! I'm not too familiar with Spring Boot myself, so great that someone already had that worked out. That `ImageIO.scanForPlugins()` alone didn't work, is hardly surprising, as this is what *creates* the problem you see (second paragraph in my link). Either use the context listener as described for Spring Boot in the link you found, or place the plugins (JARs) in the containers "shared" or "common" lib folder. Note: A full container (JVM) restart is required for this to take effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here, is a known issue with `ImageIO` plug-ins and containers (like a web/servlet container). Deploying plug-ins as part of the web application is not well supported by `ImageIO`.

The `ImageIO` [registry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/spi/IIORegistry.html) that keeps track of registered plug-ins is in effect JVM global (it is actually a registry per application context, however, there is usually only a single application context*).

- The safest option is install the plug-ins (and all their dependencies) in the container's "shared" or "common" lib folder. This ensures that the plug-ins are only installed once, and that they are available to all the container's contexts. This requires control of the container environment, and also may be a hassle to upgrade, due to manual install and full container restart required.
- If you prefer to deploy the plug-ins as part of the web application, the only option I know of, is to use the `com.twelvemonkeys.servlet.image.IIOProviderContextListener` as described [here](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#deploying-the-plugins-in-a-web-app).

  Altenatively, to use it in a Spring Boot project without a `web.xml` file, you can add the following line to the `onStartup()` method in your `SpringBootServletInitializer` subclass as described [here](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/issues/16#issuecomment-326128071):

  ```
  servletContext.addListener(IIOProviderContextListener.class);
  ```

  Note that you *must do a full restart of the container* after enabling the context listener for the first time, as the `ImageIO` may already be "polluted" from earlier deployments.

*) Not to be confused with the container's web application contexts, which there may be many of.

---

> [How can it be that] one class file (`RawImageReaderSpi`) is loaded in JVM but 
>   `RawImageInputStream` is not loaded?

This is the case mentioned in the link, where one earlier deployment of the web application has registered the `RawImageReaderSpi` class in the registry, while the rest of the classes from that deployment has been removed, due to a re-deployement. The `RawImageInputStream` class *may be* available from the new deployment, but as the new web application context uses a different `ClassLoader` instance, the original Spi class can't see it as the same class it's looking for.

Comment: Hi Herald, thanks for your help so far.
Just so I understand correctly, listener does not remove other web-apps registry shared in the same container, is that right?

I looked at the code 

`final LocalFilter localFilter = new LocalFilter(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()); // scanForPlugins uses context class loader`

above line is getting the apps context loader and removing its registered plugins. is that right?

thanks again!

Comment: That’s the idea, yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
To use this in a Maven project, you need this additional dependency:
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
To use it in a Spring Boot project without a web.xml file, you want to add the following line to the onStartup method in your SpringBootServletInitializer subclass:
servletContext.addListener(IIOProviderContextListener.class);
of course with the following import:

import com.twelvemonkeys.servlet.image.IIOProviderContextListener;


retart tomcat, and it´s work!
```