# SchemaFactory implementation by Java not found in java 6 onwards

Tags: java

I'm unable to find JDK implementation of SchemaFactory class in rt.jar of JDK 6 onwards.
SchemaFactoryImpl is available in rt.jar of jdk 5 as "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.xs.SchemaFactoryImpl"

Where can i find the implementation for SchemaFactory in jdk 6 onwards?
Has jdk come up with another class having implementation of the same?
I need this implementation to set as System Property for SchemaFactory in my project.

Please advise.

Comment: You can find many classes here: http://grepcode.com/search?query=SchemaFactoryImpl&n= but anyway I think this classes should not be for the public api

Answer (score 1):

Classes from `com.sun` are not meant to be used by application developers. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8565783/1907906