# How to make inline taglets (which require com.sun) more cross-platform? Is there a non-Oracle/more-cross-platform javadoc parser?

Tags: java, parsing, cross-platform, javadoc, taglet

I'm writing [a library](http://codelet.aliteralmind.com) that inserts *already unit-tested* example code (its source-code, output, and any input files) into JavaDoc, with lots of customization possibilities. The main way of using this library is with inline taglets, [such as](http://aliteralmind.com/docs/computer/programming/codelet/documentation/javadoc/overview-summary.html#overview_description)

```
{@.codelet.and.out my.package.AGreatExample}
{@.codelet my.package.AGreatExample}
{@.file.textlet examples\doc-files\an_input_file.txt}
{@.codelet.and.out my.package.AGreatExample%eliminateCommentBlocksAndPackageDecl()}
```

Since custom [taglets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/taglet/overview.html) (and even [doclets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/doclet/overview.html#simple)) require `com.sun`, this means they're not nearly as cross platform as Java itself. (Not sure if this is relevant, but the word "javadoc"--and even the substring "doc"--is not in the [Java 8 Language Specifications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html).)

I don't like the idea of writing a library that's limited in this way. So what do I do? My thoughts so far are that

- In order to take advantage of the existing javadoc parser, I stick with the `com.sun` taglets. However, I make this reliance on `com.sun` as "thin" as can be. That is, I put as little code in the taglet class as possible, leaving the bulk of the code elsewhere, where there is no reliance on `com.sun`.
- I work towards creating my own parser, which *only* searches for my specific taglets. This is a pain, but not too horrible. You iterate through the lines of each Java source file, searching for `\{@\.myTagletName (.*?)\}`. Once you capture that text, it's pretty much the same as the code within the `com.sun` taglet.
- This parser would have to be run before executing javadoc, and would therefore require a duplicate directory structure. (1) your original code, with the unparsed custom tags, (2) the duplicate of that code, with parsed-output. I'd copy *all* code to the duplicate directory, and then parse only those Java files known to have these taglets (classes that are "registered" in some way with the parser).

Is this a reasonable approach? Is there a more cross-platform javadoc/taglet parser out there already, so I don't have to roll my own? Is there anything cross-platform that is taglet-*like* already out there? Is JavaDoc *itself* not cross platform, or just custom taglets and doclets?

I'd like a rough perspective on how many people I'm locking out of my library because of this decision (to use inline taglets), but mostly I'm looking for a long term solution.

(Despite my Java 8 link above, I'm using Java 7.)

---

Credit to @fge for the taglet suggestion, which is more elegant than my [original idea](http://pastebin.com/ybpnY6CU), and to @Michael for the ominous-but-helpful `com.sun` warnings.

Comment: If you're interested, I've now completed this library. It's called `Codelet`: http://codelet.aliteralmind.com and https://github.com/aliteralmind/codelet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, note that there is a difference between `sun.*` and `com.sun.*` dependencies. The `sun.*`  namespace contains classes that implement Oracle's Java Virtual Machine. You [should not use such dependencies](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-141681.html#A13) because the Oracle JVM's internal API can change in future releases and because this namespace may not be provided by other, non-Oracle JVM implementations. (In practice, even [Android's JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29) [ships with one](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/a7752f4d22097346dd7849b92b9f36d0a0a7a8f3/libdvm/src/main/java/sun/misc/Unsafe.java) of the more widely used `sun.*` classes.)

Then there is the `com.sun.*` namespace which was used by [Sun Microsystems](http://www.oracle.com/us/sun/index.html) for implementing its Java applications. An example for legal use of `com.sun.*` dependencies is Sun's Jersey framework which was [originally deployed](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey) in the `com.sun.jersey.*` namespace. (For the sake of completeness, note that recent Jersey versions [are deployed](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html) in the `org.glassfish.jersey.*` namespace beginning with version 2.0 which is incompatible to the Jersey 1 API.) For further reference, note how Oracle does not even mention the `com.sun.*` namespace [when discussing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html) the problems that are imposed by using the `sun.*` namespace. Also, see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565708/what-is-inside-com-sun-package) on Stack Overflow.

Therefore, using `com.sun.*` dependencies is a different deal compared to `sun.*` dependencies. By using `com.sun.*` classes, you rather lock yourself to a specific library's API, not to a specific JVM. For example, you can avoid direct use of the `com.sun.jersey.*` namespace by using the standardized [JAX-RS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services) `javax.ws.rs.*` namespace. In this sense, `com.sun.*` dependencies are product specific and proprietary and must not be confused with Java's standardized APIs which are usually found in the `javax.*` namespace.

If I was you, I would stick with the taglets which is a mature and recognized implementation. Oracle is pretty determined [not to break APIs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-137541.html) (otherwise, they would probably also move the taglets to `com.oracle.*`) and I see no reason why they would suddenly change the taglet package structure. And if they would, you merely need to update your tech. If your application breaks for a new Java release, your users will come looking for an update of your software. Because you do not run the taglet project, I agree with you that detaching your logic from a foreign API is in general a good idea as it is for any dependency. Also, using taglets for your use case pretty much recognizes the [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principles.

Comment: I appreciate the information and the time, @raphw. Thank you. I'm going forward with taglets.

Comment: If you're interested, I've completed a beta-version on the library, and the taglet solution works very well. It's called Codelet: http://codelet.aliteralmind.com/, https://github.com/aliteralmind/codelet