# Why we get "package sun.nio.ch.sctp does not exist" type of error?

Tags: jenkins

Why we get "package sun.nio.ch.sctp does not exist" type of error? I am getting this error on Jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open JDK version 1.7.0_09 do not have this package. JDK by Oracle has this package.

Answer (score 0):

It is said in [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/nio/sctp/spec/com/sun/nio/sctp/package-summary.html) that mentioned package is since Java 1.7. Probably you have to upgrade Java on Jenkins server.

Comment: I have this version on Jenkins

Comment: java version "1.7.0_09-icedtea"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.3.4.1.el6_3-i386)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)

Comment: Do you have more details what code requires sun package? As mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565708/what-is-inside-com-sun-package that code is Oracle JVM specific and may not be compatible with other JVMs including Open JDK.

Comment: You are correct. This problem is resolved by installing java by Oracle.