# Defining a custom overrun style for a Label

Tags: java, javafx, label, javafx-8

I have created a custom color picker control for JavaFX 8. It consists of six `Slider`s in a `GridPane` with respective [`Label`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Label.html) above them.

```xml
<GridPane vgap="10" hgap="10">
    <Label labelFor="${redSlider}" text="Red"
           GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.halignment="CENTER"/>
    <!-- 5 more labels -->
    <Slider max="255" orientation="VERTICAL" fx:id="redSlider" id="redSlider"
            GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS"
            GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.halignment="CENTER"/>
    <!-- 5 more Sliders -->
</GridPane>
```

[image: color picker]

Now, when I narrow the picker, the labels' texts overflow.

[image: narrowed color picker]

What I'd like to happen here is that the texts would change to their first letters `R`, `G`, `B`, `H`, `S`, `L` instead of the clipped version with the ellipses.

`Label`'s [`textOverrun`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#textOverrunProperty) property allows setting the overflow mode to the seven values defined in [`OverrunStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/OverrunStyle.html), but none of those match what I'm looking for.

Looking inside the `Label` class, the displayed text is calculated by the [`Skin`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Skin.html). In my JDK, this goes straight to `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.updateDisplayedText()` which then calls `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.Utils.computeClippedText()`. There's really no easy way to modify this stuff by extending `Label` since it's non-portable; one would have to reimplement the entire `Skin`, which is basically the full implementation of the `Label`'s UI.

Is there a **portable** way to make the `Label`s' texts contract to a single character when overflowing other than implementing your own `Skin`?

**UPDATE:** I implemented [@VGR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831987/vgr)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38425597/1938435) as a reusable class. You can get it here: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Pietu1998/LEqXo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn’t quite what you asked for—using OverrunStyle to accomplish your goal—but it does create the same effect:

```
public static Node createCondensingLabel(String regularText,
                                         String condensedText) {

    Label regularLabel = new Label(regularText);
    Label condensedLabel = new Label(condensedText);

    StackPane pane = new StackPane(regularLabel, condensedLabel);

    BooleanBinding fullyVisible = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() ->
        regularLabel.getWidth() >=
            regularLabel.prefWidth(regularLabel.getHeight()),
        regularLabel.widthProperty());

    regularLabel.visibleProperty().bind(fullyVisible);
    condensedLabel.visibleProperty().bind(fullyVisible.not());

    return pane;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I ended up rewriting it as a reusable class. Would you mind me publishing the result as MIT-licensed snippet with attribution to you?

Comment: ++ for portability :)

Answer (score 1):

hope this helps (but it needs some improvements)

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.SkinBase;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends javafx.application.Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test");

        HBox root = new HBox();

        root.getChildren().add(getLabel("Aaaaa"));
        root.getChildren().add(getLabel("Bbbbbbbbb"));
        root.getChildren().add(getLabel("Cccccccccccccccccc"));
        root.getChildren().add(getLabel("Ddddddddddddd"));
        root.getChildren().add(getLabel("Eeeeeeeeee"));
        root.getChildren().add(getLabel("Fffff"));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private StackPane getLabel(String text) {

        final Label label = new Label(text);
        final Label gLabel = new Label(text.substring(0, 1));

        // should run after label become visible
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            for(Node node : ((SkinBase<Label>)label.getSkin()).getChildren()) {
                if(node instanceof Text) {
                    ((Text)node).textProperty().addListener((e, o, n) -> {
                        gLabel.setVisible(!label.getText().equals(n));
                        label.setVisible(!gLabel.isVisible());
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        gLabel.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red");
        gLabel.setVisible(false);

        StackPane pane = new StackPane(label, gLabel);

        return pane;

    }

}
```

Comment: This would work for _my_ JDK, but isn't portable. I'm looking for a portable solution.

Comment: The use of undocumented `com.sun` packages. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565708/what-is-inside-com-sun-package

Comment: I edited my answer, hope you find this version more portable :)

Comment: Assuming a Label skin’s first child is a Text object is not portable.

Comment: @Pietu1998 what about this version,