# SonarQube rule Classes from "com.sun.*" and "sun.*" packages should not be used

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, sonarqube

I have a J2EE project with the following characteristics:

```
CDI 1.0
Dynamic Web Module 3.0
Java 1.7 (it's being changed to 1.8)
JSF 2.0
JPA 2.0
```

I'm running SonarQube 5.6.6 rules against it and it felt into the rule

*Classes from "com.sun.*" and "sun.*" packages should not be used

squid : S1191


Classes in com.sun.* and sun.* packages are considered implementation details, and are not part of the Java API. They can cause problems when moving to new versions of Java because there is no backwards compatibility guarantee. Such classes are almost always wrapped by Java API classes that should be used instead.*

because I'm using classes **com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate** and **com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationResourceBundle**.

I've seached another threads about this and most of them say I should change the rule to exclude the specific package or class.

I think there is no point in simply circumvent the rule, so I would like to know if there are actualy java API (1.7 or 1.8) classes for these sun classes.

If not, I believe it's better to keep the alert until java API classes become available for these sun classes.

Any tip/advice on this?

Comment: The classes you are using are from a specific implementation of JSF (JavaServer Faces). JSF is not part of the Java SE standard library so you will not find equivalents in the JDK 7 and 8 API and they are also not going to be added in the future.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's a bug in SonarQube. It's overgeneralizing the `sun.*` package as mentioned in [Why Developers Should Not Write Programs That Call 'sun' Packages](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/faq-sun-packages.html) to `com.sun.*` package. This is incorrect. Oracle didn't mean to say that in abovelinked article. SonarQube should really only penalize usage of `sun.*` package or whatever is internally used by an arbitrary JRE/JDK implementation. The `com.sun.*` package is not JRE/JDK API/impl related at all.

Either turn off the S1191 rule, or mark all hits on `com.sun.*` as false positive.

#### See also:

- [What is inside com.sun package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565708/what-is-inside-com-sun-package/)
- [SonarJava issue 437](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-437)

Answer (score 0):

At least from 2021, you can include a list of packages to exclude from the rule. (See https://community.sonarsource.com/t/java-s1191-false-positive-for-com-sun-jersey/42060/3)

This exclusion list can be changed going to the rule page (java:S1191) in Sonarqube and modifying it in the appropiate Quality Profiles.