# Java official API alternative to com.sun.jna.*

Tags: java, sonarqube, jna

Our program uses native libraries through JNA, some of those calls are passing `com.sun.jna.Pointer` and `com.sun.jna.ptr.PointerByReference`.

When analyzing such code with sonar, it gives a "Major code smell" `squid:S1191 - Classes from "sun.*" packages should not be used`.
Sonar's docs specifically mention `import com.sun.jna.Native;` as noncompliant code, but does not provide any alternatives.
From googling `squid:1191`, it seems that many users think this rule is too strict (no to mention that you can't annotate imports to suppress the warning).

As I understand, this rule is originated in Java's [FAQ](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html), which also doesn't give any alternative APIs for JNA.

Should I just ignore the issue (or find a workaround to suppressing it), or are we really doing something wrong here?

Comment: I believe this question & answer matches what you're looking for: [SonarQube rule Classes from "com.sun.\*" and "sun.\*" packages should not be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43869567/sonarqube-rule-classes-from-com-sun-and-sun-packages-should-not-be-used), even if the package is different.

Comment: So really what the Java FAQ is telling you is "don't rely on internals". You are not accessing Java's internals, but simply interfacing with a dependency whose package starts with "com.sun.". I would suppress the warning.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to find a way to suppress this

Comment: You can put a comment after the first `com.sun.jna.*` import: `// NOSONAR` (optionally you can add the squid:S1191)