# Using JCodeModel, SonarLint reports classes from "sun.*" packages should not be used

Tags: java, json, jcodemodel

I am trying to use com.sun.codemodel.JCodeModel in some code that is generating Java Pojo classes from JSON schemas but SonarLint is reporting that classes from "sun.*" packages should not be used. Is there any replacement for JCodeModel in a different package that is compliant?

Answer (score 0):

Although this other thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43869567/sonarqube-rule-classes-from-com-sun-and-sun-packages-should-not-be-used) says that you shouldn't restrictedly believe in Sonar evaluation, I found this option that you should consider: [Apache JAXBUtils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43869567/sonarqube-rule-classes-from-com-sun-and-sun-packages-should-not-be-used)