# getDefaultToolkit() has a private access on toolkit

Tags: java

I have tried to set my `Image` icon but I get the error "getDefaultToolkit() has a private access on toolkit", can anybody help me?

```
@override
Public Image getIconImage() {
    Image retValue = Toolkit.getDefaulttoolkit().getImage(
            ClassLoader.getSystemResource("images/icon.png"));
    return retValue;
}
```

Comment: which `Toolkit`, that is, which package is being imported? (`Public` should cause an error, `getDefaulttoolkit()` should be unknown; correct/complete error message could help)

Comment: Import com.sun.javafx.kt.Toolkit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28918759/85421 maybe try `java.awt.Toolkit`, a supported public API?

Comment: Should be "public", not "Public"

Answer (score 0):

Based on source [here](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~ant/RT-27887/webrev.0/javafx-ui-common/src/com/sun/javafx/tk/Toolkit.java.html) looks like you need:

```
@override
public Image getIconImage() {
    Image retValue = Toolkit.getToolkit().getImage(
            ClassLoader.getSystemResource("images/icon.png"));
    return retValue;
}
```

Or as mentioned by @CarlosHeuberger, try [`java.awt.Toolkit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html).