# can't find the symbol from tools.jar

Tags: java, tools.jar

code below

```
import com.sun.tools.javac.util.Abort;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

use **javac** to compile this file, compile error like this

**com.sun.tools.javac.util doesn't exist**

I'm using mac, here is my java -version output

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_265"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_265-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.265-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Delete the unnecessary import statement?

Answer (score 0):

The package `com.sun`contains Oracle private JDK classes (see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565708/what-is-inside-com-sun-package), and the [offical statement](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/faq-sun-packages.html)).

You are running OpenJdk and this JDK doesn't include Sun's packages.

2 solutions:

- Execute your program with Oracle JDK
- Don't use those classes.

Note that using `com.sun` packages in an application is seen as a bad practice for this exact reason.