# java.* package for encoding decoding

Tags: java

I have used `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64` package for the purpose of  encoding decoding of strings. But I want to use `java.*` package for encoding and decoding instead of `com.sun.apache.*` package.

Can you please suggest an appropriate `java.*` package?

Answer (score 3):

If you can wait until **Java 8** is released - there will be a `java.util.Base64` class.
In the meantime you should use the solution from Joachim Sauer's comment. (See [Decode Base64 data in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java) - second answer)

Answer (score 0):

Use the java Packages:

java.net.URLDecoder

java.net.URLEncoder

And use it like this:

```
public static String decodeString(final String string) {
        try {
            return URLDecoder.decode(string, "UTF-8");
        } catch (final UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            TLog.d(LOG, "Decoding Not Supported");
        }

        return string;
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

What you mean?
You want to use:

```
import java.*;
```

instead of using:

```
import com.sun.apache.*;
```

?

Seems a lit bit hard. I have one way to do this:

1. Download the source code of com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64 packege.
2. Update the package name.
3. Re-package the source code.
4. Import the jar file again.

I don't think you should do this, it might be some license issue.

Comment: He means he wants to stop using the incorrect, non-portable, unsupported, fragile approach he's currently using in favor of something that is correct and robust.

Comment: Haha, Thanks for explanation. I made it wrong!

Comment: You're welcome... Though I didn't really give much explanation ;-)  Here's a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1834826/778118) that does.  I particularly like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1835670/778118).