# Decrypt C# RIJNDAEL encoded text in PHP

Tags: c#, php, encryption

I need to decrypt a string as part of an authorization process.

The documentation specifies that the authorization string was encrypted with the following settings:

- Padding of input data: `PKCS*7`
- Password byte array is 32 bytes long. Password string is converted to UTF-16 encoded byte array and byte array is then padded with zeroes up to length of 32 bytes. Longer passwords are truncated.

The C# example:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Decrypts a string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="content">The string to decrypt.</param>
    /// <param name="password">The password to use.</param>
    /// <returns>The decrypted string.</returns>
    private static string DecryptString(string content, string password)
    {
        Rijndael aes;
        byte[] retVal = null;
        byte[] contentBytes;
        byte[] passwordBytes;
        byte[] ivBytes;

        try
        {
            contentBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(content);

            //Create the password and initial vector bytes
            passwordBytes = new byte[32];
            ivBytes = new byte[16];
            Array.Copy(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password), passwordBytes, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password).Length);
            Array.Copy(passwordBytes, ivBytes, 16);

            //Create the cryptograpy object
            using (aes = Rijndael.Create())
            {
                aes.Key = passwordBytes;
                aes.IV = ivBytes;
                aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

                //Decrypt
                retVal = aes.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(contentBytes, 0, contentBytes.Length);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(retVal);
    }
```

The same function was discussed here, but for JAVA: [Decrypt C# RIJNDAEL encoded text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064529/decrypt-c-sharp-rijndael-encoded-text)

I tried to decrypt it with the following function but the result is different than expected:

```
function decrypt($string, $pass){
    $iv = substr($pass, 0, 16);
    $data =  mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
                        $pass,
                        base64_decode($string),
                        MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
                        $iv);
    $pad = ord($data[strlen($data) - 1]);
    return substr($data, 0, -$pad);
}
```

The ecrypted string `"7iTdZnp0DtGnIfwwqY4W/glbLLVZ0+asVLAuz13PzrW0wM6HC7rNuQvcG8JDSehyYeBJARdXHgLo9hRL9sBz3fN5LJ8cro3o0kFnAao2YRU="`

should decrypt to

```
"ldYWMFlSbcki6LMl3rkNfGavnt8VqmZd"
```

using the password `"GAT"`

I think it has something to do with the password / iv / encoding

Comment: You aren't showing how you encode the $pass :-)

Comment: But I can confirm that the block mode is CBC, so `MCRYPT_MODE_CBC` is right.

Comment: This is the part i don't get: `Password string is converted to UTF-16 encoded byte array and byte array is then padded with zeroes up to length of 32 bytes.`

For mcrypt_decrypt, for the key the php manual explains that - `If it's smaller than the required keysize, it is padded with '\0'.`

How should I encode the password before using it in mcrypt_decrypt?

Comment: You only need to do the Encoding to UTF16 and if necessary the cut to 32 bytes

Comment: Already tried that:
$password = mb_convert_encoding('GAT', 'utf-16le');

Comment: if you are using php >= 5.6 read http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php *5.6.0 Invalid key and iv sizes are no longer accepted. mcrypt_decrypt() will now throw a warning and return FALSE if the inputs are invalid. Previously keys and IVs were padded with '\0' bytes to the next valid size.*

Comment: PHP 5.3.3. The only warning I get is `Warning: mcrypt_decrypt(): The IV parameter must be as long as the blocksize`. Could the cipher be MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 and not MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256? (Because the IV is 16 bytes in the C# example)

Comment: Yes... Just wrote the correct piece of code below

Comment: Thank you. It works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function decrypt($string, $pass)
{
    $encodedPass = mb_convert_encoding($pass, 'utf-16le');
    $encodedPass = substr($encodedPass, 0, 32);
    $encodedPass = str_pad($encodedPass, 32, "\0", STR_PAD_RIGHT);
    $iv = substr($encodedPass, 0, 16);

    $data = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
                        $encodedPass,
                        base64_decode($string),
                        MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
                        $iv);
    $pad = ord($data[strlen($data) - 1]);
    return substr($data, 0, -$pad);
}
```

In PHP, the `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128`/`MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` isn't the size of the key, but the size of the block (see https://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/php_aes.asp). C# normally uses 16 bytes blocks, so `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128`. The size of the key is auto-detected. Note that I've moved the encoding/resizing of the password *inside* the method.