# How to sign signature data using bouncy castle?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, digital-signature, bouncycastle

```
**This is my code to sign a String.</br>**

package my.package;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaCertStore;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSProcessableByteArray;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedDataGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSTypedData;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.ContentSigner;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.util.Store;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class SignMessage {
    static final String KEYSTORE_FILE = "keys/certificates.p12";
    static final String KEYSTORE_INSTANCE = "PKCS12";
    static final String KEYSTORE_PWD = "test";
    static final String KEYSTORE_ALIAS = "Key1";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String text = "This is a message";

        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_INSTANCE);
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(KEYSTORE_FILE), KEYSTORE_PWD.toCharArray());
        Key key = ks.getKey(KEYSTORE_ALIAS, KEYSTORE_PWD.toCharArray());

        //Sign
        PrivateKey privKey = (PrivateKey) key;
        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1WithRSA", "BC");
        signature.initSign(privKey);
        signature.update(text.getBytes());

        //Build CMS
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(KEYSTORE_ALIAS);
        List certList = new ArrayList();
        CMSTypedData msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray(signature.sign());
        certList.add(cert);
        Store certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);
        CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
        ContentSigner sha1Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").setProvider("BC").build(privKey);
        gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build()).build(sha1Signer, cert));
        gen.addCertificates(certs);
        CMSSignedData sigData = gen.generate(msg, false);

        FileOutputStream sigfos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\SBI-DATA\\file\\signature_1.txt");
            sigfos.write(Base64.encodeBase64(sp.getEncoded()));

            sigfos.close();
    }
}
```

---

Now, the EnvelopedData output will be used in the process to verify the signature by this way:

```
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509CertificateConverter;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformationStore;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.util.Store;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64;

public class VerifySignature {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File p7s = new File("D:\\SBI-DATA\\file\\signature_2.txt") ;
        int size = ((int) p7s.length());
        byte[] sig = new byte[size]; 
        File f = new File("D:\\SBI-DATA\\file\\plain.txt") ;
        int sizecontent = ((int) f.length());
        byte[] Data_Bytes = new byte[sizecontent];  
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());    
        CMSSignedData signedData = new CMSSignedData(new CMSProcessableByteArray(Data_Bytes), sig);     
            Store store = signedData.getCertificates(); 
            SignerInformationStore signers = signedData.getSignerInfos(); 
            Collection c = signers.getSigners(); 
            Iterator it = c.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) { 
                SignerInformation signer = (SignerInformation) it.next(); 
                Collection certCollection = store.getMatches(signer.getSID()); 
                Iterator certIt = certCollection.iterator();
                X509CertificateHolder certHolder = (X509CertificateHolder) certIt.next();
                X509Certificate certFromSignedData = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider(BC_PROVIDER).getCertificate(certHolder);
                if (signer.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider(BC_PROVIDER).build(certFromSignedData))) {
                    System.out.println("Signature verified");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Signature verification failed");
                }
            }
    }    
}
```

---

Everything works good until signer.verify(..) due to the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignerDigestMismatchException: message-digest attribute value does not match calculated value
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation.doVerify(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation.verify(Unknown Source)
    at my.package.VerifySignature.main(VerifySignature.java:64)
```

And I really don't know what I am doing wrong. Can someone please give me a hint of what is happening?

Comment: You can avoid explicitly defining the provider using `, "BC"`. Bouncy Castle CMS works just as fine with the Oracle provider, and you may want to insert another provider in the future.

Comment: [Don't use `sun.misc.*` classes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834826/it-is-a-bad-practice-to-use-suns-proprietary-java-classes) Especially when you have a library that has a Base64 codec included!

Comment: Hey I'm facing the same issue... Have u resolved this problem ??@user3921002

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are signing it twice, once directly using `Signature` and the other one using `ContentSigner`. You need only to sign the data, not the signature.

So the solution should be to replace `signature.sign()` with `text.getBytes()`, or `text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` if you want to explicitly define a character set for `text` instead of using some system default.

Comment: I want signaure of data.

Comment: Any one knows, How to detach public key from Signature.

Comment: you're RIGHT! just get rid of that pesky Signature object and write 'CMSTypedData msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray(theRawBytesofMyFile);' and It works! tested on BC 1.49 :D :D :D