# Create instance of JAXBRIContext

Tags: java, jaxb, soapheader

I want send SOAP headers using WSBindingProvider. 
I saw an example where it's used a JAXBRIContext to create headers but I don't understand how get an instance of this class.
This is the example:

```
...    
HelloService helloService = new HelloService();
HelloPort port = helloService.getHelloPort();
WSBindingProvider bp = (WSBindingProvider)port;

bp.setOutboundHeaders(
  Headers.create(JAXBRIContext context, Object o) 
);
...
```

The method createInstance of JAXBRIContext take various parameter that I don't understand. 
This is the signature of the method:

```
public static JAXBRIContext newInstance(Class[] classes,
Collection<TypeReference> typeRefs,
Map<Class, Class> subclassReplacements,
String defaultNamespaceRemap,
boolean c14nSupport,
RuntimeAnnotationReader ar) throws JAXBException
```

Someone can explain me the parameter that I should pass to this method.
Thanks everybody in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: JAXBRIContext isn't intended to be used in application code. Isn't there an example where the JDK javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext is used?

Comment: @laune Thanks for your reply. I don't understand what you mean for "JAXBRIContext isn't intended to be used in application code", however this is the doc page where I saw the Headers.create method [link](https://jax-ws.java.net/jax-ws-20-fcs/arch/com/sun/xml/ws/api/message/Headers.html). And [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.1.7/com/sun/xml/bind/api/JAXBRIContext.java#JAXBRIContext) there is the method signature for getting JAXBRIContext but I don't understand the input parameters.

Comment: AsI said: it's a class below com.sun, and these aren't meant to be used in everyday application code; also note the comment "subject to change w.o. further notice". All of JAXB you are likely to need is available via javax.xml.bind. Why can't you use JAXBContext?

Comment: And see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834826/it-is-a-bad-practice-to-use-suns-proprietary-java-classes

Comment: @laune Actually in my application I use JAXBContext, but it's not much handy build SOAP headers. I use an HeaderHandler class where I construct the header piece by piece. With JAXBRIContext I thought I could use the objects generated by JAXB. However thanks for your help!

Comment: The context is merely an entry point and an aggregation of the types to be used. Building an XML document in "unusual" ways is more of a marshaller issue.