# with JDK 1.8, unable to extend WToolkit class

Tags: java

I am using java 1.8 version. When I am trying to extend WToolkit class, getting below error.
The type MyClass cannot subclass the final class WToolkit. is WToolkit is of type final in java 1.8?. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the class WToolkit is final in java 8:

```
 public final class WToolkit extends SunToolkit implements Runnable {
```

See the [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/awt/windows/WToolkit.java?av=f).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like sun.awt.windows.WToolkit [is final in JDK 1.8](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/awt/windows/WToolkit.java#WToolkit), and it looks like [it was not in JDK 1.7](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/awt/windows/WToolkit.java#WToolkit).

You generally [should not be using classes from sun.* packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834826/it-is-a-bad-practice-to-use-suns-proprietary-java-classes), as these are [not part of the public API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html).  In fact, in Java 9 [access to these classes will be removed](http://blog.codefx.org/java/dev/how-java-9-and-project-jigsaw-may-break-your-code/#Internal-APIs-Become-Unavailable).