# Classes from "com.sun.*" and "sun.*" packages should not be used Sonar issue for Jersey client

Tags: java, jersey, sonarqube

I am using `jersey client` for rest calls. Imports for my code are:

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
```

Everything is working fine. I am using `Sonar` for checking my Code quality.

sonar is showing a major issue for:

> Classes from "com.sun.*" and "sun.*" packages should not be used

Is this actually bad practice to use classes from sun?

If yes, what are the alternatives?

Comment: The warning about `com.sun` classes is incorrect. There are plenty of these and they are documented parts of the API. JNDI for example is full of them. It is the `sun.*` classes that must be avoided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's better to migrate to JAX-RS 2.0 client classes. Some refactoring would be necessary though. See the [migration guide](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/migration.html#mig-1.x). For example, if you wrote like this before:

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource(restURL).path("myresource/{param}");
String result = webResource.pathParam("param", "value").get(String.class);
```

You should write now like this:

```
Client client = ClientFactory.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target(restURL).path("myresource/{param}");
String result = target.pathParam("param", "value").get(String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because they are internal APIs: they are subject to change in a undocumented or unsupported way and they are bound to a specific JRE/JDK (Sun in your case), limiting portability of your programs.

Try to avoid uses of such APIs, always prefer a public documented and specified class.

Reference- [It is a bad practice to use Sun's proprietary Java classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834826/it-is-a-bad-practice-to-use-suns-proprietary-java-classes)

Comment: The com.sun. classes of the jersey library are not internal classes.

Comment: Please could you detail your comment? I read com.sun.* are internals as described above

Comment: @FGI That question is mainly about `sun.*`. Most (if not all) arguments about `com.sun.*` being private in that Q&A page lack reliable citation.