# How to sort a JavaFX ListProperty

Tags: javafx, listproperty

it seems I have encountered a problem with `ListProperties`. `ObservableLists` implement the marker interface `SortableList` that allows them to be sorted efficiently, firing only a single event. `ListProperties` do not implement this interface (how could they...?). Instead they use the default implementation of the `List` interface, firing a lot of changes.

The only solution I can see would be to call `sort()` on the underlying `List` directly. But this collides with the scheme of returning the `Property` itself:

```
public ObservableList getSomeList()
{
    return someListProperty();
}
```

which ensures that `ListChangeListener` remain registered when the underlying `List` is exchanged.

I would be happy to get some input, maybe I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the `SortableList` you refer to is the one used in `FXCollections.sort`.

`ListProperty` could implement the `SortableList` interface.

It may indeed be a good idea, since this would allow you to choose the way the wrapped list is sorted, if e.g. `FXCollections.sort` is used on the property. You could use `FXCollections.sort` on the contained list in this case.

How could they? Like this:

```
class MyListProperty<T> extends ListPropertyBase<T> implements SortableList<T> {

    ...

    @Override
    public void sort() {
        ObservableList<T> list = getValue();
        if (list != null) {
            FXCollections.sort((ObservableList<Comparable>) list);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void sort(Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        ObservableList<T> list = getValue();
        if (list != null) {
            FXCollections.sort(list, comparator);
        }
    }

}
```

The only problem is, that `SortableList` is inside the `com.sun.javafx.collections` package (see [It is a bad practice to use Sun's proprietary Java classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1834826/2991525)).

About your collision with the property scheme: there is none, if you define the property the intended way, see [*Using JavaFX Properties and Binding* section *Understanding Properties*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm#sthref10)

The property would be implemented like this:

```
private final ListProperty<MyClass> someList = ...;

public ObservableList<MyClass> getSomeList() {
    return someList.get();
}

public void setSomeList(ObservableList<MyClass> newList) {
    someList.set(newList);
}

public ListProperty<MyClass> someListProperty() {
    return someList;
}
```

The `ListProperty` has to ensure the `ListChangeListener`s registered to it receive the change events from the wrapped list.

Maybe you got confused with **readonly** list properties used in fxml, but a `ListProperty` is not readonly.

You could still use this property in a fxml file, but you'd need to use a value of type `ObservableList`:

```xml
<!-- imports -->

<ContainingClass xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <someList>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <!-- list content goes here -->
        </FXCollections>
    </someList>
</ContainingClass>
```

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. To me, it always seemed more sensible to return the Property instead of the wrapped List in the getter. That way, any Listener will stay attached and you can circumvent a bunch of errors. Yes, you can check for any Property methods. But having getter's behaviour depend on if there is a Property method seems like bad practice. Anyway, that the ListProperty shows a different behaviour when sorting seems like an actual bug to me. It has the same Interface, indicating that it works as a delegate (it does not say anything in the API docs), but does not when sorting.