# Animation of Quick Sort Algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, logic, quicksort

I am trying to animate the partition part of the quick sort algorithm using the JavaFX library. I got all the graphics portion of the program down, but I am having trouble with my step method. There is a logic error in my step method, and I can't seem to figure out what it is. The step method is supposed to do one step every time the step button is clicked.

```
private void quickSort(int lowerIndex, int higherIndex) {

    int i = lowerIndex;
    int j = higherIndex;
    // calculate pivot number, I am taking pivot as middle index number
    int pivot = array[lowerIndex+(higherIndex-lowerIndex)/2];
    // Divide into two arrays
    while (i <= j) {
        /**
         * In each iteration, we will identify a number from left side which
         * is greater then the pivot value, and also we will identify a number
         * from right side which is less then the pivot value. Once the search
         * is done, then we exchange both numbers.
         */
        while (array[i] < pivot) {
            i++;
        }
        while (array[j] > pivot) {
            j--;
        }
        if (i <= j) {
            exchangeNumbers(i, j);
            //move index to next position on both sides
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    // call quickSort() method recursively
    if (lowerIndex < j)
        quickSort(lowerIndex, j);
    if (i < higherIndex)
        quickSort(i, higherIndex);
}
```

The code above is the source code for the quick sort algorithm, the step method should do just one step of the quick sort algorithm. I tried to implement the same logic in the step method but my logic is wrong. The correct output of this program is at this link http://www.cs.armstrong.edu/liang/animation/web/QuickSortPartition.html
for reference.

Below is the code that I am working with

```
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import javafx.application.Application;
 import javafx.geometry.Pos;
 import javafx.scene.Scene;
 import javafx.scene.control.Button;
 import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
 import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
 import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
 import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
 import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
 import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
 import javafx.scene.text.Text;
 import javafx.stage.Stage;

 public class AnimateQuickSort extends Application {
    public final static int ARRAY_SIZE = 20;
    private int[] array = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];
    private int leftP = 1;
    private int rightP = array.length - 1;
    private int pivot = 0;

public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    AnimationPane pane = new AnimationPane();

    Button btStep = new Button("Step");
    Button btReset = new Button("Reset");

    HBox hBox = new HBox(5);
    hBox.getChildren().addAll(btStep, btReset);
    hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    borderPane.setCenter(pane);
    borderPane.setBottom(hBox);

    // Create a scene and place it in the stage
    Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 700, 225);
    primaryStage.setTitle("QuickSort");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    initializeArray();

    pane.repaint();

    btStep.setOnAction(e -> {
        if (step()) {
            pane.repaint();
        } else {
            pane.repaint();
        }
    });

    btReset.setOnAction(e -> {
        reset();
        pane.repaint();
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public void initializeArray() {

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 999 + 1);
    }

    // Arrays.sort(array);

}

public void reset() {
    leftP = 1;
    rightP = array.length - 1;
    pivot = 0;
    initializeArray();
}

public boolean step() {
    // quicksort(array);
    int begin = 0;
    int pivotVal = array[0];
    int array1;

    if (leftP <= rightP && array[leftP] <= pivotVal) {
        leftP++;
        array1 = array[leftP];
        array[leftP] = array[rightP];
        array[rightP] = array1;
    }

    if (rightP >= leftP && array[rightP] > pivotVal) {
        rightP--;
    }
    if (rightP > leftP) {
        if (rightP != begin) {
            array1 = array[rightP];
            array[rightP] = array[begin];
            array[begin] = array1;
        }
    }
    // Return the index of the pivot element.
    return true;
}

class AnimationPane extends Pane {
    private int startingX = 20;
    private int startingY = 20;
    private int boxWidth = 30;
    private int boxHeight = 20;

    protected void repaint() {
        this.getChildren().clear();

        int x = startingX + 10;
        int y = startingY + 40;

        // Display array
        x = startingX + 10;
        getChildren().add(new Text(x - 15, y + 55, "Array "));
        x += 20;
        getChildren().add(new Text(x + pivot * boxWidth, y + 120, "Pivot"));
        drawArrowLine(x + 15 + pivot * boxWidth, y + 100, x + 15 + pivot * boxWidth, y + 40 + boxHeight);

        getChildren().add(new Text(x - 14 + leftP * boxWidth, startingY, "Left Pointer"));
        drawArrowLine(x + 15 + leftP * boxWidth, startingY, x + 15 + leftP * boxWidth, y + 40);

        getChildren().add(new Text(x - 14 + rightP * boxWidth, startingY, "Right Pointer"));
        drawArrowLine(x + 15 + rightP * boxWidth, startingY, x + 15 + rightP * boxWidth, y + 40);

        for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(x, y + 40, boxWidth, boxHeight);
            rectangle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            rectangle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            getChildren().add(rectangle);
            if (array[k] != 0) {
                getChildren().add(new Text(x + 5, y + 55, array[k] + ""));
            }
            x = x + boxWidth;
        }
    }

    public void drawArrowLine(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
        getChildren().add(new Line(x1, y1, x2, y2));

        // find slope of this line
        double slope = ((((double) y1) - (double) y2)) / (((double) x1) - (((double) x2)));

        double arctan = Math.atan(slope);

        // This will flip the arrow 45 off of a
        // perpendicular line at pt x2
        double set45 = 1.57 / 2;

        // arrows should always point towards i, not i+1
        if (x1 < x2) {
            // add 90 degrees to arrow lines
            set45 = -1.57 * 1.5;
        }

        // set length of arrows
        int arrlen = 15;

        // draw arrows on line
        getChildren().add(new Line(x2, y2, (x2 + (Math.cos(arctan + set45) * arrlen)),
                ((y2)) + (Math.sin(arctan + set45) * arrlen)));

        getChildren().add(new Line(x2, y2, (x2 + (Math.cos(arctan - set45) * arrlen)),
                ((y2)) + (Math.sin(arctan - set45) * arrlen)));
    }
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't single-step a recursive function without coroutines (there are several libraries for coroutines in Java, but most of them tweak JVM or bytecode, so not really standard stuff).

You basically have two choices:

- Invert responsibilities, if you can: instead of animation calling single-step of QuickSort, have QuickSort call animation redraw.
- Or, in order to implement a function that does a single-step of QuickSort, you will need to unroll the recursion, which will require you to keep track of the "depth" using an explicit stack of from-to pairs. The stack starts with "whole array"; at the top of the function, you pop a state and sort that range; when you would have recursed you push the smaller range onto the stack; you are done when the stack is empty.

Comment: I need to unroll the recursion but I need to do it without using a stack, there must be a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

#### The "hacky" solution

This requires accessing the `com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit`, which isn't especially good practice, since it resides in the `com.sun` packages (see [It is a bad practice to use Sun's proprietary Java classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834826/it-is-a-bad-practice-to-use-suns-proprietary-java-classes) ).

This however allows you to "pause" the execution of a method called from the fxApplication thread until a event occurs.

Use

```
Toolkit.getToolkit().enterNestedEventLoop(loopId);
```

to "pause" the method and

```
Toolkit.getToolkit().exitNestedEventLoop(loopId, value);
```

to resume the method.

`loopId` needs to be the same `Object`.

`enterNestedEventLoop` returns the value passed to `exitNestedEventLoop`.

Using these methods you can simply add the animations to the `quicksort` method and "pause" when a step is complete and "resume" execution from the `Button` event handlers.

#### The clean solution

You basically save every state of the animation to a list so that it can be executed step by step:

Change your `AnimationPane` to support the following methods:

- `setUpperArrowPosition(int)`, `setPivotArrowPosition(int)` and `setLowerArrowPosition(int)` that change the position of the upper, pivot and lower arrows respectively.
- `swap(int, int)` this method swaps the visual representations of 2 elements of the array.

This way you not only have a cleaner design, but it's also easier to "save" the change operations to a `List`:

Create a field `List<Comsumer<AnimationPane>> steps`. Every element in this list changes the state of the `AnimationPane` to represent the state after each step using the new methods defined above. Before actually doing the sorting you initialize the `AnimationPane`. Then during the sorting you simply add all the changes that need to be done to the UI as `Consumer`s to the list for later execution, e.g. instead of

```
while (array[i] < pivot) {
    i++;
}
```

use

```
while (array[i] < pivot) {
    i++;
    steps.add(animationPane -> {
         animationPane.setLowerArrowPosition(i);
    });
}
```

You may need to adjust the algorithm a bit to correctly group the ui representations, but that should't be too hard.

After the `quicksort` method has finished, you now have a `List` of `Comsumer`s available, that change the UI to it's next state each. You can simply use a `Iterator` to get through the animation step by step:

```
Iterator<Consumer<AnimationPane>> iter = steps.iterator();
Button nextButton = new Button("Step");
button.setOnAction(evt -> {
    if (iter.hasNext()) {
         iter.next().accept(animationPane);
    }
});
```