# [JavaFX]Cannot change a rectangle color before the stage is iconified

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have this FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="900.0" style="-fx-background-color: #b8edff;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="labelme.gui.skeleton.SkeletonPageController">
   <children>
       <Rectangle fx:id="minButton" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="50.0" onMouseClicked="#minimizeWindow" onMouseEntered="#changeColorEntered" onMouseExited="#changeColorExited" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" width="900.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And also this class:

```
public class SkeletonPageController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private Rectangle minButton;

@FXML
private void changeColorEntered(MouseEvent event) {
    this.minButton.setStyle("-fx-fill: red;");
}

@FXML
private void changeColorExited(MouseEvent event) {
    this.minButton.setStyle("-fx-fill: blue;");
}

@FXML
private void minimizeWindow(MouseEvent event){
    Stage window = (Stage)((Rectangle)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    this.minButton.setStyle("-fx-fill: blue;");
    window.setIconified(true);        
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
}   
}
```

I am trying to make a rectangle that turns red/blue when MouseEntered/MouseExited event occurs. Also when I click on it, the stage should be minimized.

The problem is that when MouseClicked event occurs, the stage is iconified, but the rectangle is not changing its color. (When the stage is back maximized, the rectangle is red, instead of blue).

What's the explanation? Somehow, the stage is iconified before the rectangle color is changed? And once the stage is minimized, the color can't be changed anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. You can easily confirm this by registering a listener to the `style` property of your `Button` that prints the current style.

This seems to be caused by the UI not having enough time to redraw itself before minimizing the window but considering itself to be up to date when the window is restored.

Give the window enough time to redraw itself before minimizing and the issue is fixed.

Code that works as expected, since it ensures a additional frame occurs before iconifying the window:

```
@FXML
private void minimizeWindow(MouseEvent event) {
    Stage window = (Stage) ((Rectangle) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    this.minButton.setStyle("-fx-fill: blue;");

    AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {

        int count = 2;

        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            if (--count <= 0) {
                window.setIconified(true);
                this.stop();
            }
        }

    };

    timer.start();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Why did you say that it's not encouraged to use the com.sun classes?

Comment: @CristianZaharia: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834826/it-is-a-bad-practice-to-use-suns-proprietary-java-classes

Comment: @CristianZaharia: I rewrote the answer to use [`AnimationTimer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) instead of that `com.sun` stuff. (Why did I test this with only a single frame before :-( )

Answer (score 0):

It's not working. Better you add new method and set it's action on `MousePressed` to change color and then on `MouseReleased` action Iconified your window. I tried this and it worked.

```
@FXML
private void changeColorMousePressed(MouseEvent event)
{
    this.minButton.setFill(Color.BLUE);// OR this.minButton.setStyle("-fx-fill: blue;");
}


@FXML
private void minimizeWindowMouseReleased(MouseEvent event)
{
    Stage window = (Stage) ((Rectangle) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    window.setIconified(true);
}
```

Comment: Well, I need the color to be changed when the mouse is over the rectangle. When I press the Rectangle, it should have already its color changed. Thank you anyway.