# com.sun.glass does not exist

Tags: java, import

I have a project that is on github. I have two different computers that use the project. The reason I mention github is because the two computers have the exact same project. But on one of the computers, I get a package does not exist error. That package is com.sun.glass

```
import com.sun.glass.events.KeyEvent;
```

Underneath I tried just using

```
import com.sun.glass
```

my netbeans autocomplete shows that the package sun exists in com, but the package glass does not exist in sun. I cannot find any info about this error online, and have been searching for days. The strangest part as I said is it works on a different computer.

Both computers are running jdk 1.8.
I'm at a loss; Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's why you should not use com.sun.... imports , it's part of a JRE, but there is no assurance that is part of _all_ JRE.

Comment: So the issue could be a different JRE on the different computers? I need com.sun.glass.events.KeyEvent; program won't work without it...

Comment: [It is a bad practice to use Sun's proprietary Java classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1834826/5221149)

Comment: Did you perhaps import the wrong class, e.g. did you mean to import [`java.awt.event.KeyEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) or [`javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html)?

Comment: That section of code is not mine; I am the sole developer now but this wasn't developed by me. With minor alterations java.awt.event.KeyEvent does work though; Thank you

Comment: why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
```

the above is the preferred method of importing the KeyEvent class. There are differences between java KeyEvent and sun KeyEvent, but they are minor. For example:

```
com.sun.glass.event.KeyEvent.VK_BACKSPACE
```

is the following in java:

```
java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE
```

So after changing the import from sun to java and making a few changes to its use in the program, it works and is no longer JRE specific.